# What are the available PHP extensions for TCP Socket Networking?

Tags: php, network-programming

I'm looking for a PHP extension that allows me to connect, bind/listen, send, and receive data on a TCP socket.

There is a PEAR package Net_Socket:

http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Socket

But this would require PEAR to be installed which we wouldn't want to do as this increases memory consumption.

Is there an available purely C extension of this?

Thanks,
Kenneth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a few options:

- [PHP Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php) (available in most builds)
- [PHP Streams](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php) (5+)